# What's the best way to run a promise synchronously when it's already resolved?

Tags: javascript, promise

When a promise is resolved, it resumes code execution after any `await`s in the next task.

So for instance:

```
console.log("start");

async function foo(){
  await Promise.resolve();
  console.log("foo");
}
foo();

console.log("end");
```

prints `"start"`, `"end"`, `"foo"`. Even though the promise is already resolved, it still waits for any other code to execute first, and only after that it resumes and prints `foo`.

I would like to execute any `awaits` synchronously for resolved promises.

The only way I can think of to achieve this is to check if a promise has been fulfilled and wrap the `await` in an if statement so that it only waits if the promise is still pending. But figuring out if a promise is pending (and getting the resolved value) seems very tedious to do synchronously. Does anyone know if there's a better way?

**More context**

I have a game loop that needs to not run for more than a few milliseconds per frame. There is one specific function that I need to call in order to prepare some gltf assets. This function takes more than a second. So I'd like to devide this up into chunks, so it excecutes only part of this function every frame.

The easiest way to achieve this that I could think of was to make the function async and checking if a certain amount of time has passed. If more than a few milliseconds have passed, I will `await waitForFrameRender()`, which will essentially stop the execution until the next frame. However, this will add tons of `await`s in the function (it has a bunch of loops), and most of them won't really have to wait for anything because the function hasn't been running for more than X amount of milliseconds yet.
Therefore it seemed to make more sense to skip these waits and run these parts synchronously.

In my current setup I have an if statement to check how much time has passed, and only `await` if it has actually been running for more than a few milliseconds. Which works to a certain degree, but the function that takes a second to execute also has nested functions that are async for the same reason. So the nested function calls still need an `await`.

I realize that this sounds like web workers are the solution. I haven't actually tried this yet but I feel like transferring the javascript object that the function returns will have too much overhead for this. And since it is ok for this function to not return immediately (even 20 seconds or so would be fine) simply making the function async seemed like the easiest way to do it.

Comment: This sounds decidedly like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Perhaps make this less abstract so we can see what you're actually trying to achieve and there is almost certainly a better way

Comment: This is an XY problem.  Show us the real problem and the real code and we can then advise on a real solution.  There is NO way to get a promise result synchronously from the promise itself.  This is by design.  You would have to cache the result elsewhere and check it there first.  But, the best solution depends upon your actual problem and actual code as there is no theoretical best way here.

Comment: The problem is not with the code of `foo()`, it works as expected. The problem is with the code that calls `foo()` because it does not `await` it.

Comment: @Jamiec hey thanks! I have updated the question with more context :)

Comment: Lots of description but not much concrete to go on. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the actual problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want move end into the promise. The other alternative would be to put end in its own promise

```
console.log("start");

async function foo(){
  await Promise.resolve();
  console.log("foo");
  console.log("end");
}
foo();
```

or

```
console.log("start");

async function foo(){
  await Promise.resolve();
  console.log("foo");
}
foo();
await Promise.resolve();
console.log("end");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want. You need to `await` until foo() is done running.

```
async function run() {
  console.log("start");
  await foo();
  console.log("end");
}
run();
```